# Real AJAX uploader - set file to upload manually

Tags: javascript, file-upload, upload, ajaxuploader

I used the Real Ajax Uploader (http://www.albanx.com/ajaxuploader) for uploading files from my js/jQuery based frontend to an ASP.net based server-side function - that works well by selecting files from the file-system as via the file dialog.

But now i need to find a way to set a file (i know the exact name and local path of the file) to upload automatically via a JS function instead of selecting it manually by clicking "select file" and selecting it from the file-dialog.

I think i have to manually create a file-object and push it into the files array (because of this description to get fiel infos : http://www.albanx.com/ajaxuploader/examples.php?e=6) but I can not manage setting a file and uploading it via my js function

Any help is highly appreciated
Thanks in advance

EDIT: 
Thanks for responding Here is the code for taking a picture with the devices camera and pushing it into the files object of the uploader ...
that works so far, but i  do not know how to update the fileuploader because it seems not to have a method to do this ...
so the file is in the file-list (file_list[0]) with all the parameters i think it dioes need, but it doesnt show up in the gui-file-list

regards Don

```
<code>
// photo functions
function getPhoto(){
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoSuccess, onPhotoFail, { 
            quality: 50, 
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.NATIVE_URI
    }); 
    console.log("get photo ...");
}

function onPhotoSuccess(imageURI) {         
    console.log("photo taken ..." + imageURI);
    $('#imgUploadArea').ajaxupload('clear');
    var AU = $('#imgUploadArea').data('AU');
    var file_list = AU.files; //get all the file objects
    console.log("files: " + file_list.length);

    // get the file object 
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(imageURI, function(fileEntry) {
                fileEntry.file(function(fileObj)  
    {                               
        fileuploadShow("input.caseFormText.caseFormPhotoBtn");      
        // add the image
        var capturedImg = new Object();
            capturedImg.status = 0;
            capturedImg.name = fileEntry.name;
            capturedImg.path = fileEntry.fullPath;
            capturedImg.size = fileObj.size;
            capturedImg.filetype = "image.jpeg";
            capturedImg.ext = "jpg";
            capturedImg.AU = AU;
            capturedImg.file = fileObj;

               console.log("set image object to upload: " + capturedImg.path);      

            file_list.push(capturedImg);

        console.log("files: " + file_list.length);
            console.log("imgUpload ... imagedata path: " + file_list[0].path);
            console.log("imgUpload ... imagedata name: " + file_list[0].name);
            console.log("imgUpload ... imagedata status: " + file_list[0].status);
                    console.log("imgUpload ... imagedata size: " + file_list[0].size);
            console.log("imgUpload ... imagedata filetype: " + file_list[0].filetype);
            console.log("imgUpload ... imagedata ext: " + file_list[0].ext);
            console.log("imgUpload ... imagedata file: " + JSON.stringify(file_list[0].file));

            console.log("file added to filelist: " + file_list.length);

            var files = $("#imgUploadArea").ajaxupload('getFiles');
            console.log(JSON.stringify(files));
            //$("#imgUploadArea").ajaxupload.('renderHtml');
            //$("#imgUploadArea").ajaxupload('start');

        });
    });
}

function onPhotoFail(message) {
    alert('Photo failed because: ' + message);
}
</code>
```

Don

Comment: In the meantime I have tried a few other things, like defining the new image as a File Object (var capturedImg = new Object();) but without any luck, because it seems not to be possible to add a file to the file input listNobody who can help me out of this issue?

Comment: Normally browser for security reason will not allow adding files autoamtically without user action. For adding a file always is needed a user action(select or d&d). Think if you could do that automatically with js you can theif files from users pc. If it was what you mean